# Adding doubles to each other

Tags: java, double

I'm having trouble writing a method to calculate the total of some orders for a university project. 
Eclipse says there's an error, detailing only that the *+* is an invalid AssignmentOperator.

Some details:

- There's no privacy issues.
- *quantity* is an int.
- *getPrice()* returns a double.
- *total* is a double

It's probably something really simple, but because of that, searching around for an answer is pretty difficult.

---

```
public double calculateTotal(){
    for(OrderItem currentItem:items){
        for(int i=0;i<currentItem.quantity;i++){
            total+currentItem.product.getPrice();
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need `+=`:

```
public double calculateTotal(){
    for(OrderItem currentItem:items){
        for(int i=0;i<currentItem.quantity;i++){
            total += currentItem.product.getPrice();
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

In your example you're just adding two numbers together and doing nothing with the result. You need to assign the result to a variable. Using `+=` is shorthand for `total = total + currentItem.product.GetPrice();`

You may also need to initialize the `total` variable; but maybe it's elsewhere in your class.

Comment: Yeah, I've already initialised the variable in the constructor, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just add two values without doing something with the result. I suspect you meant

```
        total += currentItem.product.getPrice();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `+` use `+=`:

```java
total += currentItem.product.getPrice();
```